# move file from previous directory to current directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

A bit of a stupid question, I was trying to move a file thats in the parent folder, basically renaming it, and it was failing, what was I doing wrong? This is what I tried

```
move ../FILENAME.EXT ../FILENAMENEW.EXT
```

It kept saying the file was not found

Comment: Windows uses a REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) as the path separator. `move ..\FILENAME.EXT ..\FILENAMENEW.EXT` Or, the file is not in the parent directory.

Comment: Thank you, forgot that windows used that, thank you

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `rename` command if you are not actually moving the file to a different folder.  Your code is just trying to move it back to the parent folder with a different name instead of the of current directory.

Comment: In Windows, if you wrap filenames in double quotes, it doesn't matter if you use forward slashes or backslashes in filenames. CMD treats the slashes as legal when inside "path/to\file/name.txt".